# Playing a audio file in an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, audio

I am trying to play an audio file that is when the button was pressed

```
<audio controls>
  <source id="player" src="foo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
<button onclick="functionName()">Play</button>
```

When the play button pressed it has to call the function and it need to start my player , and some time i need to change the src content also when the button is pressed .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need external button to play a song. Its already there in the audio controls. Nevertheless

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioId");
myAudio.play();
```

If you want to pause externally use

```
myAudio.pause()
```

Similarly to change the source

```
myAudioSource = document.getElementById("player");
myAudioSource.src = "whatever.mp3";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks its working fine in play level but whats happening means , its playing only the src content when the page got loaded its not playing the src of dynmically injected but its getting reflected in tag also , coudl u assist me more .Thanks once againg

Comment: thanks additonally i added myAudio.load() before playing it then its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Short Explanation:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
```

**->Creates New Audio Element.**

```
audioElement.setAttribute('src', '/path/to/src');
```

**->Set the Source of the New Audio element**

```
audiElement.addEventListener("load",function(){ 
audioElement.play();
}, true);
```

**->Creates Event Listener for when the source changes, to re-load the Audio Element Attributes**

```
function Play(audioElement){

 audioElement.play();
}
```

**-> A public function to play the Audio Element**

```
<button onclick="Play()">Play</button>
```

**->Reworked Button.**

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
<script>
functionname()
{
var myVideo = document.getElementById("player");
myVideo.play();
}
</script>
```

and for changing src

```
document.getElementById("player").src="new_src";
```